# Continuous stream connectivity in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity, flutter-plugin

I've already succeeded at checking the connection on this Main Menu page, but I need this to continuously be checked at every other page in my app. Is there another way in which I could continuously check the connection without having to re-write my code everywhere? There are other questions similar to mine, but I'm a bit lost on how to implement a continuous connectivity stream from the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-) plugin package.

```
class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {

  MainMenu({this.latCoordinates, this.longCoordinates, this.postcode});

   final double latCoordinates;
   final double longCoordinates;
   final String postcode;

  @override
  _MainMenuState createState() => _MainMenuState();
}


class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  bool isConnected = false;
  bool showSpinner = false;

  void connect() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          isConnected = true;
          showSpinner = false;
        });
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        isConnected = false;
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
          setState(() {
            showSpinner = false;
          });
        });
        // showSpinner = false;
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    connect();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return isConnected ? Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ) :

    ModalProgressHUD(
      inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can upvote if the answer helped you :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64358826/10659482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [AppStateProvider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) and an app-level `showDialog()`. Keep in mind that, there is an `onConnectivityChanged` property in this package. You don't need to check connectivity on every page. It does itself. You just listen to it.

For more [information](https://pub.dev/documentation/connectivity/latest/connectivity/Connectivity-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use like this fixed for me.

```
@override
void initState() {
final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
    _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
_subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
  _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
}, onDone: () {
  _subscription.cancel();
}, onError: (error) {
  // handle error here.
});
 initStoreInfo();
 super.initState();
}
```